# prevent excel formatting as number

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have to copy from SQL Server Management Studio often. Many of our ID column fields are filled with numbers but have the data type varchar.  When copying output from SSMS to Excel MSOffice determines the column is a number and consequently strips the prepended zeroes from the number.  If I convert the column back to "text" under "Format cells," the 0 is lost.

How can I keep the zeroes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Data tab and import directly from the SQL Server. This will maintain the field types as you import and refresh the data.

[image: Maintain zeros in Front]

Answer (score 0):

Well the short answer is to format the cells that are being copied to as text before the copy. If the copy procecss is through VBA then simply tack on:

```
Range("'Sheet1'!A1:D10").NumberFormat = "@"
```

Replace "sheet1" with your sheet's name of course and "A1:D10" with your range

If simply a copy and past manually then right click on the cells, click format cells, select text.

Answer (score 0):

After you copy, Right click and select "Paste Special..."  Then select Text and press "OK"